# Problem downloading In-app icon in Apple connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In-app icon not download, problem ( There was an error with editing your App Store promotional image. Try again later.).
It's been the same error for a week, it loads on other in-apps.
What could be the problem, maybe someone has encountered such a thing?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqR4a.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the image format. The uploader isn’t very explanatory with its error messages.

There are things that don’t work like.

- Alpha channels in a PNG
- Some RGB color Spaces in a JPG

As a test try uploading something simple that you know works e.g your original icon file which should be 1024x1024 or crop a screenshot and upload that. You will then know if it’s you or them.